# Redirect to URL when SAML user not regonised

Tags: authentication, saml, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

I am using SAML and have successfully logged onto the IDP however, some users do not have accounts on the SP and I receive the following error:

"No user represented by SAML credentials could be located"

Is it possible to set a parameter so that if the user is not recognised, it redirects?

Answer (score 1):

If users don't have an account, you need to create the user record on the fly at SP. Otherwise use transient NameID format between IdP and SP, where there is no requirement to locate the user at SP.